# linq: from object in an object to just an object

Tags: c#, json, linq

Currently I'm using this linq expression:

```
(group.Select(x => ((Dictionary<string, Object>)x).GetValueOrDefault("myvalue")))
```

My problem now is that I have an object in an object.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

which makes my json look like this:

```
            "myvalue": [
            [
                {
                    "value1": "value1",
                    "value2": "value2",
                    "etc": "etc"
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "value1": "value1",
                    "value2": "value2",
                    "etc": "etc"
                }
            ]
        ]
```

How I want to look like:

[image]

So my Json looks like this:

```
            "myvalue": [
                {
                    "value1": "value1",
                    "value2": "value2",
                    "etc": "etc"
                },
                {
                    "value1": "value1",
                    "value2": "value2",
                    "etc": "etc"
                }
        ]
```

I assume I can fix it by using .SelectMany(???).ToList() but I haven't found a way to do so yet. Does anyone know how I can write it for my purposes?

Comment: How does your class look like? and can you add more info on linq you are using currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet should work

```
group
   .Select(x => ((Dictionary<string, Object>)x).GetValueOrDefault("myvalue"))
   .Where(v => v != null)
   .Select(v => 
    {
       if (v is IEnumerable enumerable)
         return enumerable.OfType<object>();
       return new [] { v }
    })
   .SelectMany(e => e)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you mind explaining to me what happens in the second .Select(v => {...}) ?

Comment: Just transformed `object` to IEnumerable<object>. Then you can use SelectMany. This code also can be moved to SelectMany lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a `SelectMany()` like an other answer suggested but if you know you always will have a single element, why not use a .First() like so

`(group.Select(x => ((Dictionary<string, Object>)x).GetValueOrDefault("myvalue")).First())`

I think